# sleep is not defined in async function?

Tags: javascript, async-await, sleep

#### Im currently working on a memory game project. A function I am trying to implement, flips cards around after two seconds instead of having them flip instantly.

```
let openCards = [];

function cardActions(card) {
    // prevent function from adding two classes over and over again 
    if (!(card.classList.contains('open'))) {
        // display the card's symbol 
        card.className += ' open';
        card.className += ' show';
        // add card to list of open cards
        openCards.push(card);
        if(openCards.length === 2) {
            if(openCards[0].innerHTML === openCards[1].innerHTML) {
                // add the match class
                Array.from(openCards).forEach(function(card){
                    card.className += ' match';
                });
                console.log('match');
                // empty open cards
                openCards = [];
            } else {
                Array.from(openCards).forEach(function(card) {
                    // add the mismatch class
                    card.className += ' mismatch';
                });
```

> at this point of the program is where I plan to flip the cards back over when the user has already looked at them.
>
> So what I did was create an asyn function called flip. I placed an await sleep inside to pause program execution but all i did was recieve 'sleep is not defined' error.
>
> I am not sure why this is happening since the sleep function IS defined inside the flip function.

```
                // flip cards around
                async function flip() {
                    await sleep(2000);
                    Array.from(openCards).forEach(function(card) {
                        card.classList.remove('mismatch')
                        card.classList.remove('open');
                        card.classList.remove('show');
                    });
                }
                // give user time to look at the cards
                flip();
                console.log('these dont match');
                // empty open cards
                openCards = [];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the code where `sleep` is defined..?

Comment: @CertainPerformance "await sleep(2000);"

Comment: There, you're *calling* sleep, not *defining* it

Comment: you havent defined sleep what are you trying to do

Comment: @CertainPerformance I thought by using sleep(timeInMilliseconds) it would pause my program for me.

Comment: There is no native sleep function in javascript

Comment: No, there's no such thing. As the error says, you have to define a function before using it.

Comment: want me to show you how to do it with timeout?

Comment: @JoeWarner sure! I would love that so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout

instead of `await sleep(2000);`
sleep is not a native stop the program but you can yield the same results with setTimeout

use

```
window.setTimeout(() => {
  Array.from(openCards).forEach(function(card) {
    card.classList.remove('mismatch')
    card.classList.remove('open');
    card.classList.remove('show');
  });
}, 2000);
```

or without an arrow function

```js
console.log('1');
window.setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('2');
}, 2000);
console.log('3');
```

Answer (score 11):

Promises are easier to deal with than `setTimeout`. If you want to use something like the `sleep` you're describing, then define a function that returns a Promise that resolves after the inputted ms:

```js
const sleep = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

(async () => {
  console.log('1');
  await sleep(500);
  console.log('2');
  await sleep(1500);
  console.log('3');
})();
```

It'll keep code flatter than using `setTimeout` and callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Using Node.js, this worked for me:

create a new function that resolves after sleep time:

```
async sleep(ms) {
            return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
          }
```

To use it, just call the function inside an async function:

```
async foobar() {
    await sleep(1000)
}
```